# Ruby NameError with BSON

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I am new to ruby so I am sorry if this question has an obvious answer but I have not had much luck with this.

But I keep running into

> uninitialized constant BSON::ObjectID (NameError)

I have the require

```
require 'mongo'
```

Then here is the piece of code that's throwing the error, collection of course points to a db.

```
#Insert and return the row.
def insert(row)
    id = collection.insert row
    collection.find_one(:_id => BSON::ObjectID.from_string(id.to_s))
end
```

I am totally at a loss for whats wrong here. seeing how ruby doesn't like me requiring bson before or after mongo.

Tried in 1.9.2 and 1.8.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was not able to 100% solve the issue, but id was already a BSON::ObjectID so I just changed it to

```
collection.find_one(:_id => id)
```

Works as I would like it to now!

Answer (score 3):

*Update*: It's Id (upper, then lower case), not ID.

Just to be sure about it, put the `require 'mongo'` in the same file as the code block above, and then change `BSON::ObjectID` to `::BSON::ObjectId`.

Comment: Yep require 'mongo' is at the top of that file, changed it to ::BSON::ObjectId also did not help. Still get the "uninitialized constant BSON::ObjectID (NameError)"

Comment: You're going to kick yourself... it's a lowercase 'd' in 'ObjectId'. I just tried it in IRB. Classic.

Comment: Weird that this isn't the accepted answer, because it's correct, or rather the above comment is.

Answer (score 1):

Try a require 'bson' in the top of your file.

Comment: Thanks, But still get a Uninitialized constant BSON::ObjectID